# Algorithm for best subset of items

Tags: algorithms

I have a matrix M with size NxN where each position M(i,j) is an integer representing the relationship between item i and j. If i and j are the same item then the positions M(i,j) and M(j,i) are 0.

What I'd need is to regroup these N items in subgroups of 5 elements each one. The value of each group would be Σ(M(i,j) for each i, j in the group).
And I would need to maximize the total value of all groups.

I studied lots of algorithms more than 15 years ago and I forgot the most of them, and nowadays are lots of new algorithms, so I'm a bit lost trying to find the best one for these case.

A friend told me to investigate Clustering algorithms but they have lots of different versions and specializations, so I don't know which one to look at first.

And just one more thing, besides this algorithm to maximize each group, would I need an algorithm to maximize the total value of all groups, discarding the non optimal selections? I remember algorithms that made this but I don't even remember their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of possible combinations grows very large, even with relatively small values of N, so one thing you could consider is some variant of the [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) if that's acceptable. Such algorithms are not guranteed to find the global optima though.

You need two things for this: a cost function and a neighborhood relation. The cost function you already gave and the neighborhood relation can be something as simple as swapping two elements between groups.

Comment: N would be always between 0 and 1000. Do you think it would be computationally intense with values near 1000?

Comment: Actually, the amount of possible combinations explode surprisingly fast (updated my answer). There's 8,25 x 10^12 possible ways to select just one group of 5 elements from the total of 1000.